# Trigger Eliminar despues de 24 hrs

Tags: mysql, trigger

Esta la forma de realizar un trigger que me elimine de mi base de datos los datos que sea inferior a 24 horas.

Tengo la siguiente tabla de reservas y en esta agrego un campo 'Tipo' que puede ser permanente o por horas, si es por horas este se eliminara en 24 horas.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Inv_Reserva` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Item` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CodPza` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tipo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=246 ;
```

Para el campo fecha utilizo `timestamp` ya que guardo la fecha y la hora.
En mi trigger preguntaria primero que me encuentre los datos con `Tipo` Hora `"DELETE FROM Inv_Reserva WHERE Tipo='Hora'"`

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es un [`EVENTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html), no un `TRIGGER`.

Traducido de la documentación de MySLQ:

> ...las **tareas programadas** de este tipo también se conocen a veces como "triggers temporales", lo que implica que estos son objetos que se activan con el paso del tiempo. Si bien esto es esencialmente correcto, preferimos usar el término **eventos** para evitar confusiones con los triggers...

Para tu caso, puedes crear un evento que se ejecute cada minuto y elimine las reservas que lleven más de 24 horas:

```
CREATE EVENT `eliminar` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2018-11-07 00:00:00.000000' ENDS '2018-12-31 00:00:00.000000' 
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO 
DELETE FROM Inv_Reserva WHERE Tipo='Hora' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,timestamp,NOW()) > 24
```

Comment: Vale entiendo ahora la diferencia de un trigger, una consulta porqye declaras el START el dia '2018-11-07 00:00:00.000000' y el END '2018-12-31 00:00:00.000000'  eso significa durara hasta el 2018-12-31 ?

Comment: Si exacto, tocaría cambiar el `END` de acuerdo a tus necesidades

Comment: Entonce puedo sacar esa variable si yo deseo?

Comment: Si, puedes quitar la parte de `STARTS` y `ENDS`